# Why was I banned from reviewing for approving a tag change on a low-rated post?

Tags: discussion

When reviewing edits, I was asked to approve a tag change for a post that appeared to be copy-pasted from someone's homework.  The post had been down-voted into oblivion, but I was not reviewing a close vote; I was reviewing a tag change.  And the tags were clearly wrong, so I approved the change.

A few minutes later when trying to review something else, I got the error

> You approved: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5263655 on a clearly spam post without taking any action against the spam. Even if it weren't spam this edit would still be too minor.

Apparently the question was later judged to be spam.  But I don't understand why I was banned for approving the tag change.  Even if I did fully read the original question, follow its link, and reach the conclusion that it was spam, the edit-reviewing UI does not given an option to reject the change on the grounds of the original question being spam.

Also, why was the edit considered to be too minor?  Tag changes aren't big changes in terms of the numbers of characters edited, but they're important in how questions get characterized.  I would expect that a tag change would *never* be too minor.

Comment: As for why the edit is too minor: the edit didn't remove the c++ or c tags, didn't put questions/answers into ordered lists, etc etc.

Comment: I don't see why that's a problem.  The edit still improved the quality of the post.

Comment: But not *all the way*, which is why it's *too minor*. =)

Comment: @nix: Spam is inherently non-quality; there is no such thing as improving the quality of spam. It's not even comparable to polishing a turd.

Comment: @BoltClock While utterly true, I'm just trying to explain why it would have been too minor even if it wasn't spam.

Comment: Are potential editors then expected to either fix *all* issues with a post or make no changes?  That seems like a good way to discourage people from ever editing posts.

Comment: Yes, potential editors are expected to fix as many issues with a post as possible when they edit, due to the impact an edit actually has (bumping, putting it into queues, etc).

Comment: Does that policy also apply to editing answers?  To editing ones's own questions, answers, and comments?

Comment: Generally, you should strive to make your edits as substantive as possible, however you are free to edit your own posts in any manner as long as you are not vandalizing them or editing only to bump them to the front page. Substantive edits is a requirement only for suggested editors (users without full editing privileges).

Answer (score 7):

Regardless of whether the edit should have been approved or rejected, the post was still a very obvious case of spam and should have been flagged; no amount of editing will change the fact that it is spam.

The message is saying that you did not take action on the post itself, which refers to the fact that you did not flag the post despite it being very clearly spam. (And for that matter, neither did any of the other users who reviewed the edit.)

We don't expect users who review suggested edits to judge other aspects of a post, however if you're looking at something that is very obviously spam, there is no legitimate reason not to flag it; allowing it to remain on the site longer is actively harmful to the site and we do not want that to happen as a result of user negligence.

Comment: In brief, [don't encourage turd polishing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77683/159251).

Comment: I question the claim of "obviousness".  Without following the link, that question looks to me like one of many copy-pasted "please do my homework for me" questions that will eventually be closed as "too broad" or "unclear" unless the poster bothers to fix them.  After skimming the linked document, I agree that the post is most likely spam.  Am I expected to fully read posts, including linked materials, before approving edits on them?

Comment: @nix: You don't need to open a link to determine if it is spam. Even absent obvious spam links, it usually does not take very thorough reading to determine that a post is spam.

Comment: ^what bolt just said. The solutions to the multiple choice quiz are at the bottom of the post, I didn't even notice there was a link. Even if it wasn't spam, it removed [javascript] from a post also tagged [java][c][c++] and left the rest of the post in a near unreadable state. That is the very definition of "too minor" - I'd take 10 edits (and 30-50 reviews) of that standard to fix that post.